# Load texture from GL.textures array

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl

I have textures that loaded into the array `GL.textures[some_index]`.
for example  `GL.textures[1]` return `WebGLTexture`.

Im trying to load it to texture in webgl:

```
var neheTexture;

function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function initTexture() {
    neheTexture = GL.textures[1];
    handleLoadedTexture(neheTexture);
}

initTexture();
```

but all I get is black screen although there is data in GL.textures[1].
What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

first, I rendered  the scene with this code, which worked, and then replaced the 'src' of the texture to GL.texture[1].

```
var neheTexture;

function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function initTexture() {
    neheTexture = gl.createTexture();
    neheTexture.image = new Image();
    neheTexture.image.onload = function () {
        handleLoadedTexture(neheTexture)
    }
    neheTexture.image.src = "nehe.gif";
}
initTexture();
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code. How should we know why nothing is displayed when you don't show the rendering code?

Comment: first, I rendered the scene with this code, which worked, and then replaced the 'src' of the texture to GL.texture[1]. added it to my Q

Comment: Are you sure the first code snippet is complete? Because there's no texture data upload call there, and by default textures in WebGL are indeed black.

Comment: Yes, the given GL.textures[1] initialized outside, you can be sure. I also checked it.
I consider the GL.textures[1] as loading 'gif' picture.
@KirillDmitrenko

Comment: The code you've posted isn't enough to pinpoint the problem. Can you create something like a jsfiddle where it can be reproduced?

Comment: It might be impossible bc Im using Emscripten and native Webgl..

Comment: forgot to mention - the texture in GL.textures[1] created as  RenderTarget texture. is that matter? @KirillDmitrenko

Comment: @DASA, yes, there may be a problem with rendering to it. What format and type so you use for it?

Comment: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gl.RGBA.
why? @KirillDmitrenko

Comment: @DASA some formats have obscure problems with rendering to them. Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: You say there is data in the texture and that you checked it. how do you check it? You can't read data from the texture in WebGL so the only way you can *check it* is to render it and since you're getting blank then there's no way you're rendering the textures and no way to could have *checked it*. So like others have said, show your code. The code at the bottom has a call to `gl.texImage2D` after the image has loaded. The code at the top shows no calls to `gl.texImage2D` and doesn't show your image loading code.

Comment: I'd recommend not using anything related to nehe. Those tutorials are massively out of date. To even work in emscripten they're going through a very incomplete emulation of old deprecated OpenGL provided by emscripten (`LEGACY_GL_EMULATION`). [Consider these ones](http://webglfundamentals.org) for WebGL or more modern OpenGL tutorials [like these](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle)